# in page jquery not firing

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page that's creating rows, which include checkboxes that have non-sequential ids.  Depending on the data from the database, sometimes they need to be checked onLoad.  The PHP is looping through the data, creating the page.

The problem: the jquery that I have within the loop is not working.  It's not checking the checkbox or firing the change event.  It's also not showing me the console.logs that I have there.  If I check the checkbox inline, that IS working, but it doesn't fire the change event and it MUST to make the page function correctly.

here's some code:

```
<? foreach($weekly as $w){ ?>

// create the row

  <input type="checkbox" id="slW_4" name="slW_4" <? if($w['current_sl_id']){echo 'checked';} ?>>

  <? if($w['current_sl_id']){ ?>
    <script language="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#slW_4').prop('checked', true);
        console.log('should have checked the checkbox: '+ $('#slW_4').is(':checked'));
        $('#slW_4').trigger("change");
        console.log('should have triggered change');
      });
    </script>
  <? } ?>

<? } ?>
```

Comment: Your doc.ready handler is inside of the loop = not correct

Comment: I highly recommend factoring your javascript outside of that loop.  Worst case scenario is that you have to reloop `$weekly` later in code.

Comment: You also output the same ID on every loop. `$('#slW_4')` will only get the first element with that ID.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara slW_4 was just an example.  I was attempting to spare you from the concatonation nightmare

Comment: @JohnC OK, I created an additional look of $weekly to the bottom of the page and moved all of this JQuery work there and it's working!  Add your answer and I'll give you credit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend factoring your javascript outside of that loop. Worst case scenario is that you have to reloop $weekly later in code.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have anything bound to listen to the change event and by default triggering a `change` doesn't do anything to the actual checkbox.

You would need a listener like:

```
$('#slW_4').on('change', function (event) {
    // ...do something here
});

// Rest of your code underneath
```

Then the `$('#slW_4').trigger("change");` would trigger that function

Also unrelated, but at the top, if you're calling `$('#slW_4')` a lot, I would store it in a variable like `var $sl4 = $('#slW_4')` and use that variable like `$sl4.prop('checked', true)`

Comment: I think you've missed an obvious problem when you say *you're calling [the same id'd result] alot*, but don't recognize it's *the same ID over and over*.